# Placing an object defined as a resource in the visual tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, window

I defined a resource which contains a button like following code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="313" Width="481">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Button x:Key="btnMy">my button</Button>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!--And now, how can I place 'btnMy' into here?-->
</Window>
```

And I like to place a control into Window1 by XAML coding.

please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to put a button in resource?

Comment: Awful way to use the controls...

Comment: I just want to know how place a resource to window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<StaticResource ResourceKey="btnMy"/>
```

If you use this in more than one place you'll get some nice exceptions...

**Edit:** It might be of interest to some that these exceptions can be avoided by setting [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) to false on the resource in question, that will cause the new creation of a control whereever it is referenced.